# PHP download/redirect

Tags: php, redirect, download

Okay so this is how I rewrote it.  Any changes?  Will this work? I've added the Javascript at the end with the timeout.

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
}
?> 
<script type="text/Javascript">
window.setInterval(function()
{
    window.location = "www.moneymovers.com";
}, 5000);
</script>:
```

Comment: This is not going to work. Once you issue a location header, the browser is free to ignore the document body (your downloaded file) and will simply load the new url.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the location header wherever you want, as long as nothing has been outputted (echo).

If you have outputted something, you can output something like this to redirect :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "www.example.com";
</script>
```

EDIT :

In your case, it is not possible to do what you're looking for, as far as I know. You will have to manage this case in the caller page. The Javascript will not be called because you've modified the Content-Disposition.

Comment: Yes, you can put it after ?>

Comment: What happened, it didn't redirect? I had forgotten the ";" at the end, maybe this will fix it.

Comment: Yes. What happens when you try to run it?

Comment: it redirects but doesn't download the file

Comment: Sorry, it sends the file but doesn't redirect.  I had a header up in the cod that I forgot about.

Comment: Remove the header redirect from your code. Also, remove "Exit;". Add my code from the EDIT after the ?> tag, and it should work.

Comment: Danny, see my rewrite on first post.

Comment: The edit is not showing the 
<?php
$file="PCI_SSC_Quick_Reference_Guide.pdf;  but i's there

Comment: See my edit, it's most likely impossible to do what you want.

Comment: Simple - I just inserted the delayed Javascript at the bottom of my Calling page in the Html - the page calls the PHP, it downloads the file, waits 5 seconds and redirects.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't download and then do a header redirect.  The client is going to redirect as soon as it sees the header, which means the download won't work.  But you also can't output the header after the download, because then the redirect won't happen.  Either way, it's not gonna work.

I would recommend doing this at a different level.  For example, when the user clicks the download link, have some JavaScript start the download in a new tab/window and then redirect to the desired location in the current tab.

Comment: It's possible to do a Javascript redirect afterwards.

Comment: In the same request as the download?  How do you figure that?  The whole point of the content-disposition header is to make the browser download the response content rather than render it, so the JavaScript will never be executed.  I even tested it and it definitely doesn't work.